# How to fix `Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$iteration` error in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-nova

Just open recent project and 'Boom' errors appear with no reason.

> Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$iteration (View: /mnt/d/web/etapas-backend/resources/views/components/landing-pages/screenshots.blade.php) (View: /mnt/d/web/etapas-backend/resources/views/components/landing-pages/screenshots.blade.php)

here is SS from my machine

http://prntscr.com/m7r3h6

Comment: Add the code that causes it. The `screenshots.blade.php` to be more precise.

Comment: what is your PHP version and what is the laravel version of project

Comment: thank you for your fast response. but actually, it's already solved when I restarting my server. It seems like the blade syntax for looping not rendering correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Error message almost identical but in Laravel
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$startSection (View: /home/steven/Documents/sphereConsultancy/sandbox/myfirstubuntu/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

This was my code in the layout.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section
<h1>My First Website</h1>
@endsection
```

Correct code- notice the added @section('content')
This was my code in the layout.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<h1>My First Website</h1>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when you have started the @section and didn't close it
add
@endsection